# log4j: custom appender and access to method from logger instance

Tags: java, logging, log4j, mule

I have a custom appender that adds the `LoggingEvent`s to an `ArrayList` of `LoggingEvent`, as follows:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton;
import org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent;

public class PayloadLogAppender extends AppenderSkeleton {
    private final ArrayList<LoggingEvent> eventsList = new ArrayList();
    @Override
    protected void append(LoggingEvent event) {
        eventsList.add(event);
    }

    public void close() {
    }
    public boolean requiresLayout() {
        return false;
    }
    public ArrayList<LoggingEvent> getAllMessages() {
        return this.eventsList;
    }
}
```

I have added the custom appender to my log4j.properties, and it gets loaded fine:

```
log4j.appender.payloadLog=PayloadLogAppender
```

Now inside my app I gain access to the logger in the usual way, using `getLogger()`,
but at the end I would like to have a hold of the list of eventsList. I have created the method `getAllMessages()` in the appender, and would like to call this when I have a hold of my logger instance. Is `logger.getAllMessage()` all that is needed to get a reference of the `eventsList` property?

Comment: What are you seeing when you try logger.getAllMessages when you use it at the end?

Comment: I'm getting this:
Caused by: java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The method getAllMessages() is undefined for the type Logger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this working with the following:

```
import mypackage.PayloadLogAppender;

// in the method that gets triggered at the end.
this.LOGGER = Logger.getRootLogger();
Appender payloadlog = this.LOGGER.getAppender("payloadLog");
System.out.println("My list of logging events" + ((PayloadLogAppender) payloadlog).getAllMessage());
```

Thanks for the pointers.